# How to get editable text value from bootstrap editable plugin

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using this [plugin](http://vitalets.github.io/bootstrap-editable/) for editing text. [This is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/4yn65v7c/3/). I want changing the text "Text 1", "Text 2" according to changing text of two edit field respectively. How can I do this?

I tried with this script:

```
var title = $('.edit_text').editable('getValue');
$('.name-list p').html(title);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is getValue? and you need to specify the type:'text',also can you post how your html looks like?

Comment: getValue is a method of that plugin. I've already given my fiddle link at where html is shown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

**DEMO: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4yn65v7c/6/)**

HTML:

```
<div><a href="#text1" class="edit_text">Name Me</a></div>
<div><a href="#text2" class="edit_text">Namete Me</a></div>
<div class="name-list">
    <p id="text1">Text 1</p>
    <p id="text2">Text 2</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
$('.edit_text').editable({
    type: 'text',
    success: function(k,val){
        var id = $(this).attr("href");
        $('.name-list '+ id).html(val);
    }
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

I was asked by someone to explain how this works. I apologize for not doing that before, this is how it works:

We first create the HTML. As you can see, the anchor tags `<a>` have a class of `edit_text` so that we can use it to attach the `.editable` methods, but also they hold the ID's they are linked to, in their `href` attributes.

In jQuery,

- we use bootstrap's `.editable` method (*[Source](http://vitalets.github.io/bootstrap-editable/)*),
- we set the default mode to "inline" so that all edits are done inline
  rather than by the default popup way `$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';`.
- we attach the `.editable` methods to all elements holding the class `.edit_text`, and we give it the options needed. `$('.edit_text').editable({..})`
- One of those options is a callback called `success` which fires when the edit is complete.
- When the `success` callback executes, it returns the index `k` and the value `val` of the current element `success: function(k,val)`
- we grab that element's `href` and assign it to the `id` variable. `var id = $(this).attr("href");`
- we look at the element with class of `name-list` and look for any children with the `id` we obtained. `$('.name-list '+ id)`
- Lastly we place whatever value `val` we received from the callback and place it inside the element found.`$('.name-list '+ id).html(val);`

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks this is also use full to me,but can you explain me how it works??

Comment: @Gomzy Hello, I included an update showing how this works. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks @CodeGodie thanks for the grt explaination... :)

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS

http://jsfiddle.net/4yn65v7c/17/

With the assumption that no. of `edit_text` is equal to the no. of `<p>` under `name-list`.
Just change your script to this

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
$('.edit_text').editable({
    success : function(k, val)
    {

      var i = $(".edit_text").index(this);
        $('.name-list p:eq('+ i +')').html(val);

    }
});
```

Comment: Though I got the solution before your answer, still thanks to you.